# Changing a node field without going to the admin section?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a page listing articles (in teaser view mode), one of the fields of the article is a taxonomy term reference.

Is there a method allowing users to change this field and save the new article with this new taxonomy term chosen by the user (without going back to the admin section, just in the teaser view mode)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Editablefields https://drupal.org/project/editablefields lets you edit many things, including terms, with ajax (without going to node edit form) but you'd have to be in fields mode.

Make a view, showing fields, and in the term's field settings you can choose "editable" and adjust some settings.

Comment: I get this error when trying to save :
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: Service unavailable (with message)
ResponseText: Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to drupal_array_get_nested_value() must be an array, boolean given, called in /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/contrib/editablefields/editablefields.module on line 315 and defined in drupal_array_get_nested_value() (line 6638 of /var/www/drupal/includes/common.inc).

Comment: OK. I was testing this with 7.x-1.0-alpha2 version with no errors. Please check the issue queue for this module.